# SSR in meteor failed to compile css from node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, antd

I'm trying to handle SSR in my meteor application, i've followed how to do SSR in meteor and react like [here](https://blog.meteor.com/meteor-platform-is-still-alive-5f6426644555), but for some reason the css from node_modules give me this error.

[image: meteor SSR error]

I'm using Nathan Reid's [css modules](https://github.com/nathantreid/meteor-css-modules) package to load css file when needed and [antd design](https://ant.design) for my components. please tell me how to solve this error and why it's showing up?

Comment: If you are doing SSR, you probably don't need to be loading CSS files - these are only necessary in the browser. Basically all SSR does is to provide the markup on the server, and deliver it to the client for display

Comment: @Mikkel so how do you implement SSR in meteor? I'd like to use `react-helmet` for my meta descriptions